How to get an image from the backend to the frontend
How to get an image from the backend to the frontend, the image is saved in /public/uploads, I have already installed @fastify/static but my route is 404, below is the code snippet.
app.register(fastifyStatic, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
  prefix: '/uploads'
})

app.get('/another/path', async function (req, reply){
    return reply.sendFile('image.jpeg')
  })

How to access images in the frontend
